# Proving that a matching has at least $\frac{|V(G)|}{2k}$ edges

Tags: graph-theory

I am given this problem in my introductory graph theory course.

Let $G$ be a graph in which the degree of every vertex is in $\{1, \dots , k\}$. Show that $G$ has a matching with at least $\frac{|V(G)|}{2k}$ edges.

I was trying to use Konig's Theorem, but I am stuck, does anyone have any hints or model solutions I can take a look at?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $M$ be a maximum matching; note that the vertices outside $M$ must form an independent set, otherwise there'd be a larger matching.
Let this be $I$; every vertex in $I$ must have a neighbor in $M$, so $I=N(V(M))$.
Thus, $|I| \leq (k-1)|V(M)|$ and adding $|V(M)|$ to both sides gives:
$n \leq |V(M)|k$, but $|V(M)|=2|M|$, so that $|M| \geq \dfrac{n}{2k}$.

Comment: Why does only a maximum matching mean that there is an independent set, wouldn't any matching mean there is an independent set?

Comment: For an arbitrary matching there may be edges among the remaining vertices; this cannot be the case for a maximum matching; if there were an edge among the remaining vertices, it can be added to get a larger matching.